# Ubuntu 0 space available, 100% use

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-18.04

When I run df -h, I see that the partition I am usually use has0 Available and 100% use. It is the Ubuntu partition, and I am not even able to boot. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I kept deleting files, but the Available and Use remain the same. I am still unable boot.

P.S. df -h output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       3.8G  962M  2.8G  26% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      787M  787M     0 100% /rofs
/cow            7.8G  242M  7.6G   4% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G  8.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/nvme0n1p1  356M  128M  229M  36% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3  313G  255G   59G  82% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4  980M  607M  374M  62% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5   20G   18G  2.6G  88% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6  122G  116G     0 100% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
```

Comment: The partition is /dev/nvme0n1p6

Comment: What's the mount point of that partition? (in actual system, not recovery environment)

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: You can't boot the system, so the easy method of simply using `mount` is out. Try to find `/etc/fstab` or `/fstab` file on one of your partitions and add its contents to the question (use the [edit] button).